# UnsupportedOperationException on GCache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying to retrieves all entries from a GoogleAppEngine cache. But when I try to call values, it will returns java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is a JCache feature that's not supported by the App Engine Java Memcache API.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache.html#Features_Not_Supported